# schematron validation using XSLT 2.0 file on net core (net 5)

Tags: xslt, .net-core, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, .net-5

I have 3 XML files which contains some rules that an XML document has to be fit in that rules.
I have converted these rule sets using oxygen xml editor to XSLT 2.0 file (some rules has XSLT function) and I need to work this XSLT 2.0 file on net core to validate an XML document against that rule set.
As I understand net core or net 5 don't support XSLT 2.0 and some library like Saxon does not support net core +.
So is there any workaround to validate XML document using XSLT file ?
How can convert to rule set to XSLT 1.0 file so net core can handle validation process. ?
Or is there any other way to do the job?

Comment: XmlPrime https://www.xmlprime.com/xmlprime/ should allow you to execute XSLT 2 with .NET core. For Saxon Java or .NET or JS 2 you will need a way to bridge from .NET Core to them running on the Java or .NET framework or Nodes.js platform, for instance by setting up a web or REST service using Saxon Java or .NET or JS 2 you can then call from .NET Core. Another option is the package https://www.nuget.org/packages/JCOBridge/, using it (with a trial license) I was able to run Saxon Java from .NET Core 5: https://twitter.com/XSLT_knowmad/status/1336786462633811969

Comment: You are correct that Saxon does not (currently) run on .NET Core (this is because Saxon for .NET is built using IKVM, which does not target .NET Core).

Answer (score 1):

SaxonCS for .NET Core 5 has been released recently and allows you to run XSLT 2 or XSLT 3 based Schematron implementations like Schxslt with .NET Core 5 or 6.

SaxonCS is available on NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/SaxonCS or from Saxonica https://www.saxonica.com/download/dotnet.xml under a commercial package.